# Do digital screens cause any permanent damage to the eyes?

Tags: ophthalmology

Is there any permanent direct damage from digital screen usage in general?
[This article](https://nypost.com/2018/08/13/your-phone-is-blinding-you-scientists-warn/) is citing a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-28254-8) that suggests the blue light may cause macular degeneration and they haven't tested in human eyes yet. [Another study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4734149/) talks about eye damage from blue LEDs. Are there any proven studies addressing the blue light produced from smart devices? Any studies about the UV light generation from smart devices? (I've read that UV rays are not emitted from digital screens but I couldn't find any paper supporting the claim.)

Should we be concerned about the blue light from screens when compared to other sources of the blue light like- fluorescent lamp and sunlight?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). We want to address claims that people are making. The first paper makes very specific *in vitro* claims. The second paper (a review, not a study) summarises the current knowledge on the subject of blue LED light (and hence should answer your question). What is the specific claim you doubt, and who is making it?

Comment: At least one of the papers shows that blue light is much lower in proportion to other colours in fluorescent light than in LED light.  I didn't notice any explicit reference to sunlight, but the intensity of blue light during the day is far far greater than what we are exposed to from screens etc.  Consider that the sky appears to be blue because there is randomly scattered blue light coming at us from all directions.